# How to use vuetify a-la-carte with laravel-mix?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, laravel-mix

I want to use Vuetify [a-la-carte](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte/) method with laravel-mix.

I have been reading the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte/#webpack-installation) aswell as this helpful [post](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/issues/49#issuecomment-557774595).

This is my full `webpack.mix.js` configuration:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');
 mix.webpackConfig({
   externals: {
    vue: 'Vue'
  }
 });

mix.options({
    extractVueStyles: 'public/css/components.css',
    purifyCss: true,
});

mix.webpackConfig({
       plugins: [
           new VuetifyLoaderPlugin({
               options: {}
           }),
       ]
   })
.js('resources/assets/js/voyager.js', 'public/js')
```

This compiles the js into a valid file in `public/js/voyager.js` aswell as the css into `public/css/components.css`.

However, the `voyager.js` contains ALL components from vuetify. I am only using `v-alert` in my files. The purpose of `VuetifyLoaderPlugin` is to only load the components that I actually use. The file `voyager.js`, is minified but still 623 kb large.

What am I missing? Why is `VuetifyLoaderPlugin` not working?

Answer (score 0):

So i assume you have did `npm run production` but your voyager.js not minified?

Afaik in mix, Minification will only take place during production builds (`npm run production`).

Comment: Sorry my question was asked a bit unclear. Minification is working, the problem is that all components are stored in my js file, and not only those that I use

Comment: Sorry for late reply, if the components that you mentioned are Vue-based, perhaps can check with `app.js` and `package.json` files that possibly routes/includes the other components that you don't need. Hope helps

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are still importing the main library from Vuetify in your voyager.js file?
Like this:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
```

If you want to use the LoaderPlugin you have to make sure that you import Vuetify from the lib folder as follows:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
```

Note the `/lib` suffix.